# "call to function log10f cannot be vectorized" with Intel Fortran

Tags: fortran, vectorization, intel-fortran

I’ve created a short example of a very simple loop that should vectorize. The message

> call to function log10f cannot be vectorized

is what I do not understand.

Why isn’t a vectorized version of `alog10` available from the library?

```
program test

real a(100)

do i = 1,100
   a(i) = a(i) = 4.31 + alog10(max(50.0, real(i)))
end do

call sub(a)

stop 
end
```

Compiled with ifort like

```
ifort -o x.o -c -O3 -xAVX -mkl -ip -fp-model precise -w -ftz -align all -fno-alias -FR 
-convert big_endian  -g  -vec_report3 -opt_report_phase hlo -opt-report-phase hpo 
-opt-report-phase ipo_inl x.f90
```

I get the report

```
INLINING OPTION VALUES:
  -inline-factor: 100
  -inline-min-size: 30
  -inline-max-size: 230
  -inline-max-total-size: 2000
  -inline-max-per-routine: disabled
  -inline-max-per-compile: disabled


<x.f90;1:12;IPO INLINING;MAIN__;0>
INLINING REPORT: (MAIN__) [1/1=100.0%]

  -> for_stop_core(EXTERN)
  -> sub_(EXTERN)
  -> log10f(EXTERN)
  -> for_set_reentrancy(EXTERN)
  -> for_set_fpe_(EXTERN)


HPO VECTORIZER REPORT (MAIN__) LOG OPENED ON Wed Dec 31 12:48:17 2014


<x.f90;-1:-1;hpo_vectorization;MAIN__;0>
HPO Vectorizer Report (MAIN__)

x.f90(6:11-6:11):VEC:MAIN__:  vectorization support: call to function log10f cannot be
     vectorized
x.f90(6): (col. 11) remark: loop was not vectorized: statement cannot be vectorized
loop was not vectorized: statement cannot be vectorized
```

Comment: New info:

-fp-model precise is keeping the loop from vectorizing. A vector version of alog10 could be used but would not provide enough accuracy to satisfy fp-model precise requirements.

As of ifort 15.0.0 -no-opt-dynamic-align is an alternative to -fp-model precise that allows vectorization.

Does anyone have experience good or bad with these two options?

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment than an answer ...

Why don't you try with a vectorised expression ?  Perhaps

```
a = log10([(I, I=1, 100)])
```

*Caveat* It's your responsibility to ensure that the syntax of the snippet is correct.